# What does @RequestMapping(value = "v1/firewall/policy/{zoneId:.*\\D+.*}") do?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what the following Rest endpoint is doing -- more specifically, the `value = "v1/firewall/policy/{zoneId:.*\\D+.*}"` part:

```
   @RequestMapping(
        method = {RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST},
        value = "/v1/firewall/policy/{zoneId:.*\\D+.*}",
        headers = "Accept=application/json"
)
public ResponseEntity post_policy(@RequestBody InformationPolicy informationPolicy,
                                  @RequestHeader("deployment-id") String deploymentId) {

    someService.process(policyInformation, deploymentId);

    return createResponse(new RestStatus(HttpStatus.OK));

}
```

I know I'm supposed to pass in some value for `"{zoneId:.*\\D+.*}"`, I've just never seen that formatting before `(zoneId:.*\\D+.*)` -- what the heck is that?

Comment: A regex I suspect. Probably for any number of digits in the zone id.

Comment: zoneId has to be anything with digits

Comment: Suggestion: don't use what you don't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part after the colon is regex. `\D` means “non digit”, so the zodeid part must contain a non-digit, ie

```
OK:     /v1/firewall/policy/12X
Not OK: /v1/firewall/policy/123
```

FYI the `+`, which means “at least one”, may be removed without having any effect whatsoever because one is at least one.

As an aside, last time I tried, if you want dots in your value you must use a regex that allows dots, eg `field:.*`, because the default behaviour doesn’t allow dots.

Comment: To complete the answer: This is documented in the "Spring Web MVC" documentation, chapter "1.4.2. Request Mapping", section [URI patterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates), about one page down: *"The syntax `{varName:regex}` declares a URI variable with a regular expressions with the syntax `{varName:regex}`"*